# CSS3 animation-play-state in shorthand is not working in IE and Safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation, safari

I am working on project having multiple animation on same element time to time and switching `animation-play-state` `paused` to `running`.

When i'm trying to add a class having animation shorthand syntax including `animation-play-state:running` then it's not working in IE & Safari.

```
.fadein-left {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 1s 2s both running;
    animation: fadeInLeft 1s 2s both running;
}
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/p39zhbtq/)

But if i use `animation-play-state` in separate line then it's working fine in all browser.

```
.fadein-left {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 1s 2s both;
    animation: fadeInLeft 1s 2s both;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/p39zhbtq/1/)

I checked animation property on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772212(v=vs.85).aspx) in **Remarks** section they just mentioned-

> However, the animation property does not specify values for the animation-play-state property.

Is it possible to use `animation-play-state` in shorthand animation or i have to use it in separate line?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? It still remains in Safari 9.0.2 (latest as of 11th Jan 2016).

Comment: @Jimbo No solution yet :(  I think it's a browser bug.

Comment: Want to submit a bug report? I'll happily back it. Also to note: if you try and set the `animation-delay` property in safari, using JavaScript, it also overwrites the whole `animation` shorthand property with just that value. I don't know if you've had that issue too, but here's my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722355/setting-animation-delay-in-safari-overwrites-animation-property-but-not-in-chro) on it.

Comment: @Jimbo i found another strange behavior regarding multiple animation on safari. I posted it couple days ago & still no solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588977/css3-animation-play-state-in-shorthand-is-not-working-in-ie-and-safari

Comment: It seems you have it working, now walk away and make yourself a cup of tea ;)

Comment: @CarolMcKay there is a workable solution but standard syntax is not working.

Answer (score 0):

try out this:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 5s;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: I already mention in post that animation-play-state in separate is a workable solution but this is not what i want.