# Setting animation-delay in Safari overwrites animation property, but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

> *Note, I am using the latest Safari (9.0.2) and the latest Chrome. I know that as of 9.0.x safari handles a lot more of the animation prefixes for you. Yay! Also, I've submitted a bug report.*

At it's most simplest, I'm trying to set the `animation-delay` **only** using JavaScript for a CSS Keyframe animation. The code is as follows:

```
el.style.setProperty("-webkit-animation-delay", "5s", "important");
```

Now in Chrome, this updates the `animation-delay` property as I expect **only**. The `animation` property is left untouched, which is what I want:

[image: Chrome Console Screenshot]

In Safari, however, this overwrites the `animation` property, which for my purposes is not okay:

[image: Safari Console Screenshot]

Obviously that's not even a valid animation value. I basically want this working in Safari without overriding the `animation` property. Is there an alternative method to achieve this?

The idea from the CSS / HTML room was to add the class to the CSS and then just toggle it with `classList.toggle`, however this animation delay property will be *dynamic and repeatedly changed. These values are NOT known beforehand*.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swakq13a/3/

Comment: Have you tried not using `setProperty`, but assigning the value directly via `el.style.webkitAnimationDelay = "5s"`? (Replace with appropriate vendor prefix where necessary.)

Comment: Yep, doesn't seem to update when using the actual name there instead of `setProperty`.

Comment: In Safari, or where? Because that works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swakq13a/5/), I'm calling `box.style.animationDelay = "5s !important";` then alerting the new `animationDelay` property - it's still blank in Chrome.

Comment: You need to include the appropriate vendor prefix in the property name. `box.style.webkitAnimationDelay = "200s";` https://jsfiddle.net/swakq13a/6/

Comment: Yep, and that brings us back to the original issue of it overwriting the "animation" key in safari, which is now "200s".

Comment: Looks like a bug specific to Safari then. // Do you need to set animation-delay values that are unknown beforehand, or a lot of different values? Otherwise the simple workaround might be to not set this value via JS, but only change/add to the element’s class via JS, and then have your stylesheet take care of formatting the element with different delays based on the class.

Comment: Unfortunately the `animation-delay` value is calculated dynamically and on-the-fly. They are unknown beforehand.

Comment: Hm, then you could possibly try and read all `animation-*` properties beforehand – so that you can assemble the “full” value from those, and then assign it as the new value of the `animation` shorthand property … Or create/manipulate stylesheet rules dynamically.

Comment: Bug-wise, I can't find anything out there describing similar issues. I was thinking about something like your suggestion... `animation.duration + "s " +
                    animation.timingFunction + " " +
                    animation.delay + "s " +
                    animation.iterationCount + " " +
                    animation.direction + " " +
                    animation.fillMode + " " +
                    animation.playState + " " +
                    animation.name;`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - I just saw that this question was a year old. This answer should help anyone Googling for this exact issue, apologies if it is a year too late for you, Jimbo.

I was able to resolve the issue in Safari (while keeping everything functional) by just resetting the entire animation property with shorthand. This might not be 100% ideal, but it does circumvent the Safari bug without creating any animation issues that I can see.

Here is an example JS Fiddle showing it with a variable value: https://jsfiddle.net/andrewborem/5rb5ybe3/1/

NOTE - I removed the "important" argument on setProperty since it is no longer necessary. Additionally, I removed the `animation-delay` property from the CSS.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var box = document.querySelector('#box');
    var variableDelay = "5s";
    box.style.setProperty("animation", "cycle-wide 2s " + variableDelay + " ease-in-out infinite both");
    alert(box.style.animation);
}, 1000);
```